# Limit OAuth scopes Firebase requests from Facebook login in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am using Firebase Facebook social login for my Flutter app. When it is launching login window for Facebook, it has a label where it is displaying login with email or phone number message.

I would like to restrict it to just ask for email only. How can I achieve this?